# cleveref doesn't use correct capitalized name if used with amsthm?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, capitalization, amsthm, cleveref

It seems that the `cleveref` package does not capitalize properly when referring to a newtheorem if both `\crefname` and `\Crefname` have been defined. Or is it just me? Here is my MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
 \crefname{theorem}{theoLowercase}{theoLowercaseS}
 \Crefname{theorem}{TheoUpperCase}{TheoUppercasesS}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}\label{theo:test}
    Test theorem
 \end{theorem}
 This is a reference to \cref{theo:test}.

 \begin{figure} Test Figure
    \caption{Test figure caption}
    \label{fig:test}
 \end{figure}
 This is a reference to \cref{fig:test}.
 \end{document}
```

On my machine, the refrence to the theorem uses the lowercase version if both `\crefname` and `\Crefname` are defined, namely :

> This is a reference to theoLowercase 1.

If I comment out the `\crefname` definition on line 5, I get the expected:

> This is a reference to TheoUpperCase 1.

In both cases, 
the reference to the figure is correctly capitalized though.

Am I crazy?

Comment: It is the expected behavior, since you are explicitly defining it with `\crefname`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Seems to be "by design". Quoting from section 6.1 of the `cleveref` manual:

> [With the `capitalise` option,] [a]ll the default cross-reference
>   formats will [...] have the first letter capitalised, as will the
>   automatically generated `\cref` variants [...] (However, if you
>   explicitly define a `\cref` variant to not be capitalised, `cleveref`
>   will still honour your denition. In other words, you're responsible
>   for defining the capitalisation correctly in your own format
>   denitions.)

If you want your custom definitions to be respondend to the `capitalise` option, use the internal `\if@cref@capitalise` conditional:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\if@cref@capitalise
\crefname{theorem}{TheoUpperCase}{TheoUppercasesS}
\else
\crefname{theorem}{theoLowercase}{theoLowercaseS}
\fi
\makeatother
\Crefname{theorem}{TheoUpperCase}{TheoUppercasesS}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{theo:test}
   Test theorem
\end{theorem}
This is a reference to \cref{theo:test}.

\begin{figure} Test Figure
   \caption{Test figure caption}
   \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
This is a reference to \cref{fig:test}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `capitalise` option if you want `\cref` references to be capitalised in common cases.

If you define your own command (in your case `\crefname{theorem}{theoLowercase}{theoLowercaseS}`), when you use `\cref` referred to a `theorem`, the package `cleveref` "respects" your definition (not capitalised).

You can notice that it works if you delete the two definitions of yours:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{theorem}\label{theo:test}
    Test theorem
 \end{theorem}
 This is a reference to \cref{theo:test} and \Cref{theo:test}.

 \begin{figure} Test Figure
    \caption{Test figure caption}
    \label{fig:test}
 \end{figure}
 This is a reference to \cref{fig:test} and \Cref{fig:test}.
 \end{document}
```

[image]