# cleveref capitalise option not working with babel translations

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, cleveref, capitalization

When using the cleveref `capitalize` option, all my references should be capitalized. But this is only working if I do not add new `babel` translations.

Running the following example results in `figura` instead of `Figura`:

[image]

And if I comment out my line `\addto\captionsbrazil{\crefname{figure}{figura}{figuras}}`, then the `capitalize` option starts working again:

[image]

How to fix the cleveref `capitalize` option when using it with the babel package?

How can I report this as bug to cleveref package maintainers?

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{abntex2}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise]{cleveref}

\addto\captionsbrazil{\crefname{figure}{figura}{figuras}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\Crefname{figure}{Figura}{Figuras}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hi}

See the \Cref{acode,afigure}.

\Cref{afigure}.

\Cref{acode}.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code,label=acode]
Code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{Figure}
\label{afigure}
Figure
\end{figure}

Something...

\end{document}
```

Related questions:

1. [cleveref doesn't use correct capitalized name if used with amsthm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126020/cleveref-doesnt-use-correct-capitalized-name-if-used-with-amsthm)

---

## Update

Following [@Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001) suggestion to not use `\addto\captionsbrazil` does not work because by default instead of showing `Figura` its shows `Fig.`, then I need to use `\addto\captionsbrazil` to override this `Fig.` abbreviation:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{abntex2}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Listagem}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise,brazilian]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hi}

See the \Cref{acode,afigure}.

\Cref{afigure}.

\Cref{acode}.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code,label=acode]
Code
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{Figure}
\label{afigure}
Figure
\end{figure}

Something...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add the option `brazilian` to the list of options employed when loading the `cleveref` package. I.e., something like this:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,twoside]{abntex2}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Listagem}
\usepackage[nameinlink,capitalise,brazilian]{cleveref}
```

If you prefer to get "Figura" rather than "Fig.", simply add the option `noabbrev` to the list of options with which you load the `cleveref` package.

With this setup, the two `\addto\captionsbrazil` instructions shown in your code don't seem to be needed.

Comment: I updated the question with this example.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted this answer accidentally, and unfortunately I cannot undo it.

Comment: @JavierBezos - Thanks for the heads-up. I've applied a minor edit to the answer; you should be able to undo the vote now. :-)